# GDAL version different if called from Windows Powershell and shows "ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w, shell, powershell

I have two GDAL installation, one from the OSGEO4W installer and one from [Tamas Szekeres’ Windows binaries](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows). I set the necessary variables according to the article.

I open Powershell and ran `gdalinfo --version` and got many errors like this

> ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program
> Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_BAG.dll 193: %1 is not a valid Win32
> application.

Also, the GDAL version returns but it's an old version `GDAL 1.6.0, released 2008/12/04`. The GDAl in my OSGEO4W shell is `GDAL 3.3.1, released 2021/06/28` and GDAL 303 Command Prompt `GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01`. I use a 64-bit device.

[image]

My GDAL system variables are set accordingly also and `C:\Program Files\GDAL` is added to my `Path` system variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Apparently, in my `Path` system variables, there was a directory pointing to the GDAL 1.6 file. I removed it, removed also the 3 GDAL variables stated in the article. Added those 3 variables again and Powershell now says `GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01`.

https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows